# Open new Page preference in new window

Tags: apex, actionfunction, pagereference

i want to open new page as new window...
in the beginning i  used apex:CommandLink and  `target="_blank"` and it  worked well.

But i want to add validation in java-script so i used in `Apex:ActionFunction` 
So i want to know **how  can i open new page from action function in new Window .**

***I appreciate if you can answer...***

**Javascript:**

```
   function PdfReport(id)
         {
         var selectCheckbox = false;
         var tab =  document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
               for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
                { 
                   if (tab.rows[j].cells[0].querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked == true )
                   { 
                        selectCheckbox = true;  
                   }  
                }
        if(selectCheckbox  == false)
           {
                alert('You must select at least one technology in order to export ');
                return;
            }
         exportPdf();   
         }
```

**Apex page:**

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!Export}" name="exportPdf" />

<apex:commandLink rendered="{!visible}" styleClass="exportTo" value="export result to Pdf" id="exportPdf"  target="_blank"
  onclick="PdfReport('mainPage:mainForm:pageBlock:sectionSearch:searcResult_:result:blockdetail'); return false"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)?

Comment: no cause i  am open the new page from the controller

Comment: A server can't tell a browser to open a new window or tab; the action has to be initiated from the browser-side e.g. straight after PdfReport calls exportPdf.

Comment: actionFunction could also do URLFOR to a VF page that displayed the PDF

Comment: That right thanks a lot for your comment its help me a lot ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So after research i cant redirect new page in new window from server side , so used in other method :
first of all i make validation in java script and if it return true the action in the controller running  ,

**JavaScript**

```
 function PdfReport(id,type)
         {
         var selectCheckbox = false;
         var tab =  document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
               for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
                { 
                   if (tab.rows[j].cells[0].querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked == true )
                   { 
                        selectCheckbox = true;  
                   }  
                }
        if(selectCheckbox  == false)
           {
                alert('You must select at least one technology in order to export ');
                return false;
            } 
            return true;
         }
```

**Apex:**

```
   <apex:commandLink rendered="{!visible}" styleClass="exportTo" value="export result to Pdf" id="exportPdf"  target="_blank"  action="{!Export}" onclick="return PdfReport('mainPage:mainForm:pageBlock:sectionSearch:searcResult_:result:blockdetail','Simple');"  />
```

**the idea from :**
[How to add a confirm dialog to a command button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/how-to-add-a-confirm-dialog-to-a-command-button)